# Filtros con Macro Excel

Tags: vba, excel-2013

Espero puedan ayudarme con lo siguiente.

Tengo una hoja en Excel, en la que requiero hacer cierto tipo de filtros.

Criterio 1:
Columna A;
Contiene fechas y requiero filtrar la fecha más reciente. La fecha esta de esta forma "Mes y Día, ejemplo September 12".

Se como poner Autofiltros con criterios en macro pero con fechas no he podido filtrar la ultima fecha.

Ejemplo de filtro con criterios filtrando el valor 10 de la columna AG que es la No 33:

```
Sheets("Nombre de la hoja").select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AG").Autofilter Field:=33, Criteria:="">=10" , Operator:=xlAnd
```

¿Alguna idea, para solo filtrar la ultima fecha?

Estos son mis datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es tu codigo que agregue a mi Macro:

```
 Sub FechaMax()

Dim FechaMax As Range

Sheets("CalcPromedios").Select
Sheets("CalcPromedios").Activate

With Application.WorksheetFunction
       Set FechaMax = Range("A" & .Match(.Max(Range("A:A")), Range("A:A"), 0)) 'cambiar A por la columna que tiene las fechas
End With


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AG$65536").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FechaMax.Value 'cambiar el área de aplicación y el número de field
Set FechaMax = Nothing

End Sub
```

Y subi un ejemplo a mi drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17UWq1OFkFEodAq0bCkqnwmbEjHDxt6cC/view?usp=sharing

DS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La fecha más reciente será la fecha de mayor valor en toda tu columna de fechas. Se puede calcular, y entonces buscar su posición dentro de la columna. Una vez localizada la primera celda que contenga la fecha más reciente, entonces se aplicará el filtro.

Un ejemplo sencillo que he hecho yo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fecha más reciente sería 09/09/2018, que aparece 2 veces. Mi código:

```
Dim FechaMax As Range

With Application.WorksheetFunction
       Set FechaMax = Range("A" & .Match(.Max(Range("A:A")), Range("A:A"), 0)) 'cambiar A por la columna que tiene las fechas
End With


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FechaMax.Value 'cambiar el área de aplicación y el número de field
Set FechaMax = Nothing
```

Y el resultado tras ejecutar la macro, es que me filtra por fecha más reciente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedas adaptar el código a tus necesidades.

Comment: Gracias por contestar 
He tratado de adaptar tu codigo pero no me ha funcionado me muestra el siguiente error:
Run-time error '1004':
Unablew to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction dass

Ademas te comento mi celda (Fechas) tiene el siguiente formato.
Wednesday,March 14, 2012

Espero me puedas ayudar.

DS
@Elier Sánchez E-Infantes

Comment: ¿El formato de las celdas es Texto? Edita tu pregunta y pon un pantallazo de tus datos, así como el código que has adaptado del mío, por favor.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes
Subi una pantallazo y un ejemplo a mi Drive.

De antemano gracias.

DS

Comment: Vale, he visto tu archivo. Fijate que en mi código las fechas están en la columna A, porque yo lo hice basándome en la columna A. Tienes que cambiar las letras de la columna A por las letras de la columna donde  tienes tú las fechas, y también cambiar por el número de campo que quieres filtrar. Y también cambiar el área de aplicación a tus datos. Tienes puesto `"$A$1:$AG$65536"` y eso es toda la hoja!.

Comment: Disculpa Elier, pero segun veo la columna en la que tengo las fechas es la correcta.
Edite de nuevo la pregunta agregando un nuevo ScreenShoot

Comment: En esa columna primera, las fechas están en texto, no en fecha. Aunque tengas metido formato fecha en la celda, el valor que hay dentro de la celda no es un número,sino un texto.

Comment: Perdona, es correcto lo que comentas. Ya hice la prueba y funciona correctamente tu codigo.
Pero entonces al ser texto, como puedo convertirlo a Fecha (Numero) dentro del macro sin agregar otra columna.

O filtrar ya sea con la celda tipo texto, lo que pretendo es que el usuario no modifique los datos ya que estos los toma otro Macro que hacer ciertas operaciones y graficos.

DS
@Elier Sánchez E-Infantes

Comment: Pues veo 2 opciones: 1) Que te hagas otra macro personalizada que te transforme todas las fechas de texto a fechas normales. 2) Otra opción sería que, cuando te traigas los datos, ahora te los traes como texto, pero podrías traértelos como fecha modificando la macro supongo. Sin ver el input de tus datos, ni como los traes, no puedo decir más. En cualquier caso, eso sería otra pregunta, no en esta.