# El filtro no se esta aplicando VBA

Tags: excel, vba

quiero que los 5 filtros se apliquen sobre la hoja, pero el ultimo (filtro de la fecha) me sale en blanco aunque la fecha la esta tomando correctamente :( Alguna idea?

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim hoy As Date
    Dim fechaVisita As Date

    hoy = Date
    fechaVisita = DateAdd("d", -30, hoy)

    MsgBox (fechaVisita)

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CAPFD"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="<>*rym*", Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:=Array("Contactado", "Datos Erróneos", "Espera POS", "Imprimir Configuración", "Problemas En POS", "Sin Contacto", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("abonavetti", "acorrea", "ameza", "amuradas", "cbento", "clatapie", "smeza"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & fechaVisita, Operator:=xlAnd        
End Sub
```

Comment: no sé si te es posible, pero yo añadiría hasta tres columnas y haría en una =DIa(CeldaDeLaFecha), la siguiente =MES(CeldaDeLaFecha), y por último =Año(CeldaDeLaFecha).
De este modo puedes después filtrar números, lo cual es mucho más simple, ya que excel y las fechas es muy lioso, ya que te cambia la fecha a americano, o incluso cuando lo tienes bien no quiere filtrarlo... separa la fecha en día mes y año y si sólo tienes datos del mes, con el día te basta, si tienes datos de varios meses con día y mes, si tienes con años pues las tres columnas.

Comment: A la hora de usar fechas como filtro a través de macros, dan algunos problemas. Es curiosísimo porque muchas veces la propia macro que graba el grabador no sirve. Pero en mi caso, lo que siempre me ayuda es si la fecha es un rango. Podrías llevarte la fecha que usas de filtro con VBA a un rango, y entonces desde ahí aplicas el filtro. Mira el ejemplo de esta respuesta, que no hace exactamente lo que tú quieres, pero sí aplica como filtro una fecha https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198288/74355

Comment: Hola, la solucion la encontre rondando por internet, era restarle los 30 dias y pasar la fecha a tipo long, finalmente guardarla en otra variable:

    Dim Dhoy As Date
    Dim Lhoy As Long
    Dhoy = DateAdd("d", -30, Date)
    Lhoy = Dhoy

Por ultimo el filtro hacerlo con la variable creada y funciona 10 puntos, gracias igualmente por los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Aca esta la solucion:

```
Sub Bienvenida_Visitas()

Dim Dhoy As Date
Dim Lhoy As Long
Dhoy = DateAdd("d", -30, Date)
Lhoy = Dhoy
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="CAPFD"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="<>*rym*", Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:=Array("="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>mad", Operator:=xlAnd
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BC$50000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & Lhoy

End Sub
```

Comment: y si explicas ese código?